# How to get more than 20 lines of output with grep when searching for a string with spaces

Tags: shell, grep, macintosh

I am currently using grep like this:

```
grep search_string search_file > output_file
```

Here is an example:

```
grep "ich arbeite" deu.txt > out.txt
```

When used in this way, I only get the last 20 matches in out.txt. I think this is because the search_string contains a space and quotation marks, because when I try:

```
grep arbeite deu.txt > out.txt
```

...I get the expected result (all matches show up in out.txt)

How can I get grep to return all matches when I search for a string containing spaces?

EDIT: My input looked like this:

```
...
I wonder why.   Ich frage mich, warum.
I work a lot.   Ich arbeite viel.
I'll ask Tom.   Ich frage mal Tom.
...
I wish Tom wouldn't keep bothering me with questions.   Ich wünschte, Tom würde aufhören, mich mit Fragen zu nerven.
I wonder if Tom realizes how many hours a day I work.   Ich frage mich, ob Tom klar ist, wie viele Stunden täglich ich arbeite.
...
```

Comment: `grep` always returns all matches; something else is going on.

Comment: @Michael Homer My initial search string was "ich arbeite" with the quotation marks. When I tried just arbeite without quotations it gave the full output.

Comment: Does that mean your issue is resolved? Otherwise, you can [edit] in details of what you're actually doing and what the actual results are versus what you expect.

Comment: For the case that I'm currently trying it's resolved, but I would like to be able to search for strings containing spaces in the future.

Comment: You can. If you have a concrete example of something not behaving as you expect, please [edit] it into the question so that people can help you.

Comment: (Include some sample *input* from your file as well as the commands)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that using quotations as I had done returns only case-sensitive matches (of which there were exactly 20). Changing the search_string to

> "Ich arbeite"

subsequently returned all the matches where the first 'I' is uppercase. The reason why I hadn't noticed that was because most of the early matches that I was looking for had the I in uppercase, while the later matches which I wasn't looking for had the I in lowercase.

Comment: You can use grep's `-i` flag to trigger case-insensitive matches next time ;-)